# Editing Django _form.as_p

Tags: django, django-forms

By default _form.as._p spits out:

```
<p><label for="id_subject">Subject:</label>
    <input id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100" /></p>
```

Whereas I need

```
 <p><label for="id_subject">Subject:</label><p>
    <input id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100" /></p>
```

with a break between the label and the input. How can I modify my Django code to do so?

Comment: it's not xml valid what you are trying to write.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You simply just can't use `form.as_p` anymore. If the defaults don't work for you, then you must render the fields manually:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Answer (score 7):

If you just need a break, then there's no need to change the Django code. Just use CSS to style `label` as `display: block`.

Answer (score 7):

Override as_p on your form class.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def as_p(self):
        "Returns this form rendered as HTML <p>s."
        return self._html_output(
            normal_row = u'<p%(html_class_attr)s>%(label)s</p> %(field)s%(help_text)s',
            error_row = u'%s',
            row_ender = '</p>',
            help_text_html = u' <span class="helptext">%s</span>',
            errors_on_separate_row = True)
```

Comment: I imagine the choice between overriding as_p or iterating through form fields in the template will depend on a variety of project-specific factors. If you need all your forms to display this way, iterating through forms fields in the template could become a maintenance burden when you later want to tweak the display. Overriding as_p may or may not be the best solution for the OP, but I doubt it is the wrong approach "in general".

Comment: It is when it changes expected behavior. Granted, the small change is probably inconsequential, but it sets a precedent for making larger more drastic changes later. As a developer who has inherited Django code that would make the worst PHP developers laugh, I can say that convention and expected behavior are absolutely crucial to a well-designed app. Any Django developer, at any time, anywhere, should be able to sit down with your code and work with it immediately. If that's not possible, you're doing it wrong. That and "Explicit is better than implicit." It's core Python mantra.

Comment: DRY is also a core mantra, which your approach will tend to violate on sites with lots of forms. And overriding methods is hardly a violation of "convention and expected behavior" in OOP.

Comment: If you want DRY, then move the template loop into a separate file and include it. That's not an argument for this approach over the more explicit in-the-template approach. And it is when you fundamentally change what the method does. Overriding a method to add additional behavior is one thing, but when a method returns one thing on 10,001 Django sites and something different on 1, that's a problem.

Comment: Moving a p tag "fundamentally changes what the method does"? Real-world decision-making is more complicated than your categorical answers imply. Best practices often conflict with each other and choices are required (for example, optimized code is often not the most readable code). In some organizations compatibility with 10,001 other Django sites is not in fact the highest priority. Many organizations could not use Django if they could not modify Django's behavior to suit their needs. That that creates more work for a developer inheriting the codebase may be an acceptable cost.

Comment: This is a very good approach!! I just would use a different method name on a base class. Also, underscore access isn't wrong for the class itself, but for others.

Comment: How to achieve this in ModelForm?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much what Brian describes above. I would write a new method for your form like as_myp. I made this for myself. I took as_table method and made as_plain to remove the tr/th markups. Ex.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field1 = forms.CharField(...)
    my_field2 = forms.WhateverField(...)

    def as_myp(self):
        "Returns this form rendered as HTML <p>s."
        return self._html_output(
            normal_row = '<p%(html_class_attr)s>%(label)s</p> <p>%(field)s%(help_text)s</p>',
            error_row = '%s',
            row_ender = '</p>',
            help_text_html = ' <span class="helptext">%s</span>',
            errors_on_separate_row = True)

    def as_plain(self):
        "Returns this form rendered as HTML <tr>s -- excluding the <table></table>."
        return self._html_output(
            normal_row = '%(label)s%(errors)s%(field)s%(help_text)s',
            error_row = '%s',
            row_ender = ' ',
            help_text_html = '<br /><span class="helptext">%s</span>',
            errors_on_separate_row = False)
```

It just seemed easier to do that than write a template file and handle form field rendering with errors, tags, visible/hidden, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way `{{ form.as_p }}` renders the html by providing an alternative *p.html* template and pointing to it in `Form.template_name_p`.

This could be the form definition:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    template_name_p = 'some_app/p.html'  # The new template for as_p()
```

This is the default *p.html* (found at *django/forms/templates/django/forms/p.html*):

```html
{{ errors }}
{% if errors and not fields %}
  <p> {% for field in hidden_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}</p>
{% endif %}
{% for field, errors in fields %}
  {{ errors }}
  <p {% with classes=field.css_classes %}{% if classes %} class="{{ classes }}"{% endif %}{% endwith %}>
    {% if field.label %}{{ field.label_tag }}{% endif %}
    {{ field }}
    {% if field.help_text %}
      <span class="helptext"{% if field.auto_id %} id="{{ field.auto_id }}_helptext"{% endif %}>{{ field.help_text|safe }}</span>
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
      {% for field in hidden_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </p>
{% endfor %}
{% if not fields and not errors %}
  {% for field in hidden_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

It creates the html that the OP wanted to avoid, namely:

```
<p>
    <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" ... [attributes removed for brevity] >
</p>
```

Here is a modified *p.html*, where the call to `{{ field }}` is wrapped in its own `p` element. (I also changed the parent `p` to a `div` because Chrome doesn't like nesting `p` tags).

```html
{{ errors }}
{% if errors and not fields %}
  <p>{% for field in hidden_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}</p>
{% endif %}
{% for field, errors in fields %}
  {{ errors }}
  <div {% with classes=field.css_classes %}{% if classes %} class="{{ classes }}"{% endif %}{% endwith %}>
    {% if field.label %}{{ field.label_tag }}{% endif %}
    <p>
      {{ field }}
    </p>  <!-- New: p tag wraps field -->
    {% if field.help_text %}
      <span class="helptext"{% if field.auto_id %} id="{{ field.auto_id }}_helptext"{% endif %}>{{ field.help_text|safe }}</span>
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
      {% for field in hidden_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
{% if not fields and not errors %}
  {% for field in hidden_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This alternative *p.html* can be placed in the relevant app templates directory as *some_app/templates/some_app/p.html*. It produces the html that I think the OP wanted.

```
<div>
    <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
    <p>
      <input type="email" ... [attributes removed for brevity] >
    </p>
</div>
```

Docs reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/api/#as-p

****Update** per the comments below on the `TemplateDoesNotExist` error: This solution may require that you not place the *p.html* in a central templates directory but in a templates directory for the relevant app, which is an easy distinction to miss. Again per the comments below, it sounds like there are work arounds to that limitation.

Comment: I tried to do this:

```py
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    template_name_p = 'some_app/p.html'  # The new template for as_p() 
```

but I got a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error, as it seems to search inside the Django package (`django/forms/templates`) instead of the templates of my app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your template *some_app/p.html* located literally within `some_app` or is it within a central templates directory. I ran into a similar `TemplateDoesNotExist` error with the above solution. I had my *p.html* in my main templates dir (e.g. `my_project/templates/some_app/p.html`) rather than within the app itself (e.g. `my_project/some_app/templates/some_app/p.html`). I believe the solution above requires placing *p.html* literally in the relevant app. This thread may provide some more clues: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/form-template-name-issue-templatenotfound/11451/11

Comment: Oooh!  You are absolutely right: I have my templates folder in the project's base directory.

I had not found that thread, but yeah, that workaround works!  Thank you  :-)

Shouldn't that behaviour be reported as a bug in Django?
Or is there any better way to customize the rendering of a form?

Comment: Found it!  In order to keep our custom template in our central template directory, we have to do two things in our `settings.py` file:

1. explicitly register `django.forms` in our `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. define `FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'`

It now works like a charm in my Django 5 project.

Answer (score -6):

Template:

```
<div id="my_form">
    {{ form.as_p }}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#my_form p label,
#my_form p input{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

So if you add fields you can still use form.as_p

Comment: I like this idea of manipulating how as_p renders by manipulating the tags themselves although i think it might go against the spirit of css.